# How to increment the counter under array of object nested array of object

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a dataset like this.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5db02ff6f13fb935bc390c80"),
    "tag" : "#Test",
    "counter" : 6.0,
    "activity" : [ 
        {
            "userid" : "5c35f1045643180d9488112f",
            "Holder" : [ 
                {
                    "id" : "5db02fedf13fb935bc390c7f",
                    "count" : 1
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Now I want to increment the count of `count` key which is under the Holder array.

I wrote the query But that doesn't work.

```
db.CollectionName.updateOne({
 {tag: "#Test", 'activity.userid': '5c35f1045643180d9488112f'},
 {$inc: {'activity.$.Holder.count': 1}}
})
```

that genearte an error and not increment the counter. Any help or suggestion is really appreciared for that. Thanks in advance

Comment: how do you identify Holder element to update? (Holder is an array)

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple array syntax

```
db.CollectionName.updateMany({tag: "#Test", 'activity.userid': '5c35f1045643180d9488112f'},{$inc: {'activity.$[].Holder.$[].count': 1}})
```

Comment: could you please share the error. I have tested this on 4.0

Comment: The error is: It can not use `activity.$[].Holder.$[].count` this path to traverse the element.

Comment: I believe this was not a part of mongodb 3.4 release as per release docs. You should upgrade your version.

Comment: Yes, True, it is supported In a higher version.